# Regex to extract string from xml text

Tags: java, regex

I have several lines and documents of text that contain lines like these. I want to extract data that occurs after **"pn="** and put it in a map where in the case below **group** becomes my key and **Fulton_County_Grand_Jury** the value. Need help with building a regex to extract this.

```
 <wf cmd=done rdf=group pos=NNP lemma=group wnsn=1 lexsn=1:03:00::
 pn=group>Fulton_County_Grand_Jury</wf>
```

Comment: Why are you using a regex to read XML ? There are native XML tools that you could use

Comment: Better use an XML parser, not a regex, to process XML, unless you have full control over the documents and know for certain that they do not have comments, nested structures, and other structural issues that make the XML language irregular.

Comment: Here is a good start to see what exist nativly on [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2545439 ;)

Comment: @PieterDeBie That was a great read! In my defense, I also saw this - "If you have a small set of HTML pages that you want to scrape data from and then stuff into a database, regexes might work fine. " :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way would be to use an XML parser.

Apart from that, you have to look for `pn=`, its end, and the part between `>` and `<`. Something like this

```
<wf.*? pn=([^ >]+).*?>(.*?)<
```

Comment: thanks! This gives me the entire string "pn=group>Fulton_County_Grand_Jury</wf>" Will need to further extract group and Fulton_County_Grand_Jury.

Comment: I modified your answer a tiny bit and am able to get both group and  Fulton_County_Grand_Jury through m.group(1) and .mgroup(2). Funnily though, when I print these individually I get the correct values but when I try to print them together I get an exception saying "no match found"  Here's the code : String str = "pn=group>Fulton_County_Grand_Jury</wf>";
  
   final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("pn=([^ >]+).*?>(.*?)<").matcher(str);
      while (m.find()) 
       System.out.println(m.group(1));
          System.out.println(m.group(2));

Comment: This may be due to missing braces around both System.out.println

Comment: @ Olaf Dietsche Sorry, my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex, with this pattern: **"pn=(.*?)>"**

```
    final String hex = "<wf cmd=done rdf=group pos=NNP lemma=group wnsn=1 lexsn=1:03:00:: pn=group>Fulton_County_Grand_Jury</wf>";
    final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("pn=(.*?)>").matcher(hex);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Neither =, nor <, or > are meta characters on its own. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Yes, provided pn= is always exactly before the closing >.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Thanks for the answer! Both the regexes you shared work and m.group(1) gives me the key value i.e. group. Still need the value. Maybe use substring for that?